# How can I prevent changes to formula results after first use?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

We have an Excel 2013 workbook that we use when we create new user accounts (column A for first name, column B for last name, column C for the password, etc.).

```
First name      Last name       Password
John            Doe             #s$r28
Jane            Doe             #s$r29
Some            User            #s$r30
```

The format of the password text is basically something like #s$r28 (this column is currently using static text).  When we create a new user, we use the fill handle in Excel 2013 to copy the last row in the sheet down to the next row, which increments the contents of the cell for the password column by 1 (one) so that the password for the new user in the newly copied row would become #s$r29, and then the next one copied would end up being #s$r30, and so on.  However, this method isn’t what I would call a best practice and doesn’t generate a truly random password.

I can generate a random password simply by using a formula like:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(97,122))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(33,47))
```

But my problem is that any update to the Excel sheet causes the formula to fire off again and Excel updates all of the previous passwords that were displayed for the entire password column.  That is OK technically but the workbook is kept for historical purposes and I would like to create a random password that doesn’t update every time a row is copied.  I’ve searched but haven’t been able to solve my problem.  I don’t think that I want to replace the contents of the formula in the new cell with the results of the formula (if that is even possible) because we still need to copy that to the next row whenever we create the next user (so the password column cell needs to remain as a formula I think).  So is it even possible to have a formula only fire off when a row is copied to a new row?  Or is it possible to create a formula in Excel that only fires off one time?  Or is there some other way that I’m just not seeing that might work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very concept of formulae is that they fire again and again. You can disable them from doing so by fixing their values only. If you want a fix value you may resort to using VBA.
 I would add a Sub that creates the password when you call it, like this:

```
Sub ertdfgcvb(Target As Range)
For Each Cell In Target
    Cell.Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(97,122))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(33,47))"
    Cell.Value2 = Cell.Value2
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This led me to look at putting together a VBA solution (still work in progress), but I'm building one to generate truly random passwords (random p/w length min/max, character placement, etc.).  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Calculate once, copy the range of formulas, then Paste Special (right-click target, then <kbd>S</kbd>) the Values only back into the range. This replaces the formulas with their results and will prevent the random passwords from being recalculated.

Comment: Good idea, but the problem is the next time that I go to use the last row, the formula will be gone (because I replaced it with the value).  Thank you

Comment: A workaround that I've used for this is to have a dummy row (maybe above your table) that still holds the formula. If you need the formula for new entries, you can copy it from that cell.